# Replace string taken from another column in pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, replace

I am trying to do a replace across one column of a pandas dataframe like the below.

From:

```
a          b
house      ho
cheese     ee
king       ng
```

To:

```
a        b
use      ho
chse     ee
ki       ng
```

My attempt is to use:

```
df['a'] = df['a'].str.replace(df['b'], "")
```

but I get TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed

I have done it by iterating row by row across the dataframe but its 200,000 rows so would take hours. Does anyone know how I can make this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because performance is important here is possible use list comprehension with `replace` for replace per rows:

```
df['a'] = [a.replace(b, "") for a, b in df[['a','b']].values]
```

Another solution is slowier with [`DataFrame.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html):

```
df['a'] = df.apply(lambda x: x.a.replace(x.b, ""), axis=1)
```

---

```
print (df)
      a   b
0   use  ho
1  chse  ee
2    ki  ng
```